# Css hide the red line (is a span) from out of div?

Tags: html, css

Please refer to attached
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4ieM.png)

How can hide the red line (its a span) from out of div?
Margin left not worked because the line left the other side.
How can fix it?

```css
@keyframes linewidth1 {
    0%{
        border-bottom: 4px solid white;
        width: 0%;
    }
    25%{
        border-bottom: 4px solid white;
        border-bottom: 4px solid white;
        width: 0%;
    }
    60%{
        border-bottom: 4px solid white;
        border-bottom: 4px solid white;
    }
    75%{
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    }
    90%{
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #e10000;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #e10000;
    }
}
.line2 {
  left: 0;
  animation: linewidth1 3s;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e10000;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 57px;
}

.single_style {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 234);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
  border-bottom-color: cadetblue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 57px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 11px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-left-color: cadetblue;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-color: cadetblue;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-top-color: cadetblue;
  border-top-left-radius: 170px;
  border-top-right-radius: 39px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 4px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="single_style" style="height:200px;">

    <span class="line2"></span>

  </div>
</body>
```

How can hide the red line (its a span) from out of div?
Margin left not worked because the line left the other side.
How can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create this line using background:

```css
.single_style {
  background:linear-gradient(#e10000,#e10000) 0 57px/100% 2px no-repeat;
  animation: linewidth1 3s;

  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 234);
  border-radius:170px 39px 11px 57px;
  border-top: 4px solid;
  border-right: 2px solid;
  border-left: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  border-color: cadetblue;
  margin:5px 3% 5px 20px;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

@keyframes linewidth1 {
    0%,25%{
        background-size:0% 2px;
        background-image:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
    }
    60%{
        background-size:100% 4px;
    }
    75%{
       background-size:100% 0px;
        background-image:linear-gradient(#fff,#fff);
    }
    75.01%{
       background-size:100% 0px;
        background-image:linear-gradient(#e10000,#e10000);
    }
    90%{
       background-size:100% 2px;
        background-image:linear-gradient(#e10000,#e10000);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="single_style" style="height:200px;">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @AliJafary we can also animate gradient ;)

Comment: how can animated the gradient like new edit of my code with animate?

Comment: you are genus bro <3

Answer (score 2):

added `overflow: hidden;` to  `.single_style`

```css
.line2 {
  left: 0;
  animation: linewidth1 3s;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e10000;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 57px;
}

.single_style {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 15px;
  background-color: rgb(238, 238, 234);
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: auto auto;
  border-bottom-color: cadetblue;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 57px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 11px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-left-color: cadetblue;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-right-color: cadetblue;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-top-color: cadetblue;
  border-top-left-radius: 170px;
  border-top-right-radius: 39px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-top-width: 4px;
  border-right-width: 2px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-top: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="single_style" style="height:200px;">

    <span class="line2"></span>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: In this case, a new problem arose, other objects hided when page resized. for example some text hiding instead warp to next line

Answer (score 0):

Float the span to the right side and decrease its width to 95%

```css
.line2 {
  left:0;
  animation: linewidth1 3s;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e10000;
  width: 95%;
  float: right;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 57px ;
 }
  
  .single_style{
 position: relative;
 padding-top: 15px;
 background-color: rgb(238, 238, 234);
 background-repeat: repeat;
 background-size: auto auto;
 border-bottom-color: cadetblue;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 57px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 11px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-left-color: cadetblue;
 border-left-style: solid;
 border-right-color: cadetblue;
 border-right-style: solid;
 border-top-color: cadetblue;
 border-top-left-radius: 170px;
 border-top-right-radius: 39px;
 border-top-style: solid;
 border-top-width: 4px;
 border-right-width: 2px;
 border-left-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 3%;
 margin-top: auto;
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 }
```

```html
<body>
<div class="single_style" style="height:200px;">
 
 <span class="line2"></span>
  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: its not good work in my template. because my template is relative and a lot of other object is int the single_style div